# Text-indent is moving elements (anchor tags) off the page

Tags: html, css

I have a list that uses pictures in the navigation without any text. It appears that they have gone to the background and I am having difficulty trying to fix it. I want to be be to click the images and for them to bring me to another page. I am pretty new to this. I was using CSS to do this.

```
<div id="navigation">
    <ol>
    <li class="news"><a href="news.html">news</a></li>
    <li class="review"><a href="review.html">Review</a></li>
    <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li class="photos"><a href="photos.html">Photos</a></li>

    </ol>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS:

```
#navigation li {
float: left;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 0px 0 0;
text-indent: -9999px;}

#navigation li.news {
background: url( "news.png" );
display:block;
width: 308px;
height: 80px;
list-style:none;}

#navigation li.review {
background: url( "review.png" );
width: 308px;
height: 80px;
list-style:none;}

#navigation li.contact 
{
background: url( "contact.png" );
width: 308px;
height: 80px;
list-style:none;}

#navigation li.photos 
{
background: url( "photo.png" );
width: 308px;
height: 80px;
list-style:none;}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text-indent` is moving the `<a>` tags off the page because `<a>` is `display: inline` by default. It is treated sort of like text in this case and gets indented. You could do this instead:

```
#navigation li {
float: left;
height: 30px;
margin: 0 0px 0 0;
}

#navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Though I'm not sure why you want the text there at all.

**Check out this demo: http://jsbin.com/ejeGufa/2/edit**

You can tell that the `<a>` tags are now in the correct place because the cursor changes (or you can inspect the element in the dev tools).

By the way, you can avoid repeating code by doing this:

```
#navigation li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  display:block;
  width: 308px;
  height: 80px;
}

#navigation a {
  display: block;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation li.news {
  background: red;
}

#navigation li.review {
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: This works now, thanks very much. Just realised I didn't need the indent or the text in the list. I was using a ridiculous way of getting rid of text.

Comment: @user2977102 no problem! You might want to do that on some old questions also. It helps other viewers know what answer was most helpful and gives credit to the person that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. Adjust accordingly.

```
#navigation a {
    display: inline-block;  //or block
    width: 308px;      //adjust accordingly
    height: 80px;      //adjust accordingly
}
```